# How to update a gridview after saving data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have one grid view with 4 columns(UserId,Description,Password,Change Password[Button]).

When i click on change password the panel with 3 textboxes(UserID,New Password,Confirm Password) and save button appears.

After changing password the panel disappears but the password in the gridview remains same as previous.

I want to update the password column.

Following is my Save Button Click
Code

```
protected void BindGridView()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["userinfo"];

        gvPassInfo.DataSource = dt;
        gvPassInfo.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //lblMessage.Text = DataObjects.Error_Message();
    }  
 }
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    clsUser objuser = new clsUser();
    string user = txtUserid.Text;
    string NewPassword = txtNewPassword.Text;
    string ConfirmPassword = txtConfirmNewPassword.Text;
    objuser.UpdateSystemPassword(user, NewPassword);
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Password Changed   Successfully...'); document.location='" +ResolveClientUrl("~\\PasswordInformation_Details.aspx") + "'; </script>");
    BindGridView();
    panelChangePassword.Visible = false;

   }                                                                                     
protected void btnSearch1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(clsUser.connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "select DISTINCT user_id,description,sap_system_password from sap_password_info where user_id is not null";
            if (txtSid.Text !="")
            {
                strQuery += " AND sid = '" + txtSid.Text + "'";
            }
            if (txtClient.Text != "")
            {
                strQuery += " AND client_no = '" + txtClient.Text + "'";
            }
            if (txtUser.Text != "")
            {
                strQuery += " AND user_id = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            }

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            Session["userinfo"] = dt;
            Response.Redirect("~\\PasswordInformation_Details.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //lblMessage.Text = DataObjects.Error_Message();
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }

}
```

The code is in C# and back end is MySQL DB Server.. please help..

Comment: Bind it again to the (updated) datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `GridView` at the end of your **update event/save** button click event

### Edit

you are updating the record in the database but you are not fetching new data that's the reason you are getting old information

so after following statement fetch the data from database and update the session dataset with new data then your problem will solve...

```
 objuser.UpdateSystemPassword(user, NewPassword);
 //get the updated data from the database after this statement
 //don't forget to update the session with new data
```

### Write this code in old page

```
Dictionary<string,string> infor = new Dictionary<string,string>();
infor["sid"] = txtSid.Text;
infor["client_no"] = txtClient.Text;
..
...
Session["queryInfo"] = infor;
```

### In New File

```
GetDataFromDB()
{
Dictionary<string,string> infor = (Dictionary<string,string>)Session["queryInfo"];

try
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(clsUser.connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "select DISTINCT user_id,description,sap_system_password from sap_password_info where user_id is not null";
        if (infor["sid"] !="")
        {
            strQuery += " AND sid = '" + infor["sid"] + "'";
        }
        //... do like above for remaining if conditions

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
        Session["userinfo"] = dt;
        //Response.Redirect("~\\PasswordInformation_Details.aspx");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw;
}
}
```

Comment: @Abu first can you show me the logic, how you get the data from the database and storing in session

Comment: I just  written a BindGridview() method and nothing else to get the data.

Comment: @Abu may be you are wrote to get the data from the database in different page search your project where you are actually storing datatable in the session. Its like `Session["userinfo"] = <your datatable name>;`

Comment: Juz see the question again, i have edited it with search button code in another page. i think this is the code to get data from DB.

Comment: @Abu So call that code again your problem will solve, you may need to save the Sid, client_no and user_id in the Session

Comment: But how i call that code in another page? The search btn code is in diffrent page.

Comment: @Abu store the information needed to call the query in session and copy the code and create a method in actual page paste it and replace the info with session information

Comment: Problem solved  Just created a method "RefreshGridview" and copy the code of search button in that method and remove those if conditions../ Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

in the button_click event, bind your gridview to a new list.

```
List<something> k = //your sql stuff
GridView1.DataSource = k;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i havent written any click event. instead written gridview_RowCommand and gridview_RowEditing events. how to bind it again?

Comment: can you show us some more code? the gridview in .aspx page, and the row_command and row_editing from the .cs file would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Read this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=107). And there are so many tutorials for the beginners of ASP.NET on internet. Google it..

**Edited:** After save of password ,load your `datatable` from database(not from session) and bind it again to your gridview.

like that

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = //LoadFromDB();    // load data from database not session

gvPassInfo.DataSource = dt;
gvPassInfo.DataBind();
```

Comment: lol please edit your original answer with this code, like this it's just unreadable

Comment: I m not getting this line dt = //LoadFromDB(); after dt= i m juz getting Load option.

Comment: thats why you should seriously consider reading some tutorials first.. you must have some method tucked away somewhere that returns a List<T> of users and passwords. you just call objuser.NameOfThatMethod(); so, gvPassInfo.Datasource = objuser.NameOfThatMethod(); ..

Comment: bt y i need to write method for that? i have BindGridview method in which i m binding the data from database..

Comment: @Abu: you updates the password in database, So it is obvious that you should load updated data from database, not from session. just call once again your load data logic that you used to bind gridview. Plz think something logical yourself :(

Comment: that's wat i want to explain you. yes, call BindGridview() method again after update password funcionality

Comment: still it is not working. pwd changes but gridview is not refreshing.